# MySQL SystemD Logfile Permission Denied

Tags: centos, permissions, systemd, mysql

I've installed MySQL 5.6 on a CentOS 7 server and I'm trying to change the error log location from the default `/var/log/mysql.log` to `/var/log/mysqld.err`. MySQL is running properly when I use the default file location, but the systemd service fails with `err 13 - Permission Denied` when I try to change the logfile location. I made sure to set the file access permissions and owner/group and restart the service with the following:

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysqld.err
chmod 640 /var/log/mysqld.err
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mysql
```

but the mysqld service still fails with the Permission Denied error when it tries to log output into `/var/log/mysqld.err`.

I've even tried setting the file access permissions on `/var/log/mysqld.err` to 777. In this case, the `mysqld_safe` script was able to write to the logfile successfully when I ran it manually, but the systemd service still fails even though I allowed any user to edit the file.

Are there settings other than file access rights and owner/group settings that limit what files a systemd service can access? As a side note, I have made no modifications to the service script that is installed from the MySQL repo, nor have I added any overwrite files for the service.

Comment: Did you check SELinux permissions? If its log is hardcoded in an SELinux rule, you'd have to add an other for your new file. looking at the file `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for denied entries as well as checking what gives `semanage fcontext --list |grep mysql` would give some informations about this

Comment: And a complimentary chcon (before correction) or restorecon (once fixed) could help. `chcon -v --reference=/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysqld.err`

Comment: @A.B You were right about the SELinux permissions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A.B was correct about the problem being with the SELinux permissions. The new file needed a `mysqld_log_t` type. I fixed the issue by changing the type:

`chcon -t mysqld_log_t /var/log/mysqld.err`